# linear combination of images gives me error

Tags: python, opencv

let us consider following code

```
import  numpy as np

import cv2 as cv

imag1 =cv.imread('logos.jpg')
imag1 =cv.cvtColor(imag1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
shape1 =imag1.shape
print(shape1)
imag2 =cv.imread('arduino.jpg')
imag2 =cv.cvtColor(imag2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
shape2 =imag2.shape
print(shape2)

imag2 =cv.resize(imag2,(shape1[1],shape1[0]))

cv.imshow('logos',imag1)

cv.imshow('arduino',imag2)
result1 =cv.addWeighted(imag1,0.2,imag2,0.8,0)
cv.imshow('result1',result1)
alpha =0.5
result =alpha *imag1 + (1-alpha)*imag2
cv.imshow('result',result)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

built in function of python- cv.addWeighted  works fine, but when i am trying to implement second one, it gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dato/Downloads/python_environment/weighted.py", line 23, in <module>
    cv.imshow('result',result)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:261: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::CvtHelper<struct cv::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)
```

size of images  are (223, 400) ,(223, 403), that why i applied resize function to make images equal to each other, but i can't understand what is the reason of error? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method results in values that can potentially be fractional values. Since intensity values are integer values between 0 and 255, you want to round the resulting values of your linear combination, and then set the data types as uint8.

```
result = alpha * imag1 + (1 - alpha) * imag2
result = np.around(result).astype(np.uint8)
```